# installation of pymongo works but fails at import in python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.10 and tried to get pymongo to work properly under python3. Things I have tried:

```
1. apt-get install python-pymongo
2. python setup.py install #from git source
3. easy_install pymongo
4. easy_install pymongo3
5. pip install pymongo
6. pip install pymongo3 #needed a fix in the download script
```

I have also removed and cleaned between the installations as best as I could.

If I import pymongo:

```
In [1]: import pymongo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ec8fdd1cd630> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymongo

/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pymongo-2.4.2_-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/__init__.py in <module>()
     55     return '.'.join(map(str, version_tuple))
     56 
---> 57 version = get_version_string()
     58 """Current version of PyMongo."""
     59 

/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pymongo-2.4.2_-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/__init__.py in get_version_string()
     51 
     52 def get_version_string():
---> 53     if isinstance(version_tuple[-1], basestring):
     54         return '.'.join(map(str, version_tuple[:-1])) + version_tuple[-1]
     55     return '.'.join(map(str, version_tuple))

NameError: global name 'basestring' is not defined
```

The error is the same as [pymongo FAQ](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/python3.html#why-do-i-get-a-syntax-error-importing-pymongo-after-installing-from-source) but for me it doesn't matter where I'm located.

My theory is that the python2 version of pymongo has mistakenly been added python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with

```
sudo python3.2 setup.py install
```

but it doesn't for some reason

better of downloading the source for distributed and pip (and install them in this order) by

```
sudo python3 setup.py install #distributed
sudo python3 setup.py install #pip
sudo pip-3.2 install pymongo
```

Answer (score 1):

In case I needed it in the future.

Installation of pymongo in ubuntu13 for python3

(1)Do not install the pymongo directly in the ubuntu software center; they are for old version of python (before version 3)
[image]

If you install it, you'll not be able to use pymongo in python3:
[image]

(2)You should install a specific python package installer for python 3: python3-pip
[image]

(3)use the pip-3.3 command python3-pip package provided, run the following command in terminal of unbuntu to install pymongo:

```
pip-3.3 install pymongo
```

If you don't have super user privilege, run it with sudo

```
sudo pip-3.3 install pymongo
```

(4)Then you should have no difficulty in install pymongo which can be used in python3. To verify it, type in IDLE:

[image]

(5)You can also install pymongo3 without difficulty in the terminal:

```
pip-3.3 install pymongo3
```

But there is no need to install it because all its functionalities are included in current pymongo package now.

Comment: It changes its name to pip3, so type "pip3" instead. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Installation with pip3 worked for me

```
sudo pip3 install pymongo
```

To use pip3, As a prerequisite Python 3 copy of pip has to be installed which can be done as follows

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try it:   Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for pymongo

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest pymongo(3.4.0) from *https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo#downloads*
2. Extract the files: *tar -zxvf pymongo-3.4.0.tar.gz*
3. Run the installation by firing: *python3 setup.py install*

**Note:** Of course you will need to fire the aforementioned command inside your extracted pymongo directory.  You may also need to run it as root otherwise you will get write permission issues. I am using CentOS 7 and it worked like breeze!.