# How to install PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am currently trying to install MongoDB driver for Python on my Mac OS X (mavericks).

But when I run

```
[ Dsl  ~/Documents/python ] sudo easy_install pymongo
```

I get the following output

```
Searching for pymongo
Best match: pymongo 2.7
Processing pymongo-2.7-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg
Removing pymongo 2.7rc1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding pymongo 2.7 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.7-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for pymongo
Finished processing dependencies for pymongo
```

I try a lot of different commands, but nothing work. How to install pymongo ?

Thanks for your help

Edit: When I try to use it in a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pymongo

client = MongoClient()
```

I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mongo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

Comment: there does not seem to be any error in the install, does it not work?

Comment: I think fireup a terminal and see if you can import PyMongo package

Comment: When I try to use it I have 
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'

Comment: The script is using python3, but pymongo is installed only in Python2.7 - you need to install it for the correct version of Python you are using.

Comment: It's work with Python2.7 but I need to use it with python 3. (I have Python 3.4.1 with the problem No module named 'pymongo')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation of pymongo works but fails at import in python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879527/installation-of-pymongo-works-but-fails-at-import-in-python3)

Comment: try this : http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/installation.html#installing-from-source Installing from source

Answer (score 6):

Try these commands. [Source](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0.1/installation.html)

```
$ easy_install -U setuptools
$ python -m easy_install pymongo
```

Comment: It's work with Python2.7 but I need to use it with python 3. (I have Python 3.4.1 with the problem No module named 'pymongo')

Comment: @AnthonyPradal ImportError: No module named flask_pymongo same error for me as well. How to tackle?

Answer (score 6):

I have same error , and I can fix it following command.

```
sudo pip3 install pymongo

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Try this. but this command for Ubuntu 14.04 OX.not sure is this work in Max OS X.

Answer (score 4):

```
python3 -m pip install pymongo
```

worked for me in OS X

Comment: This was already recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039057/4634527).

Answer (score 2):

Installing pymongo goes very simple

Make sure that **python** is installed already in your machine.If not check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757656/how-to-install-a-module-for-python-2-6-on-centos/47048568#47048568) for quick installation.

**CentOS**:

Update using yum

```
yum -y update
```

Download the pip using curl:

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
```

Install pip command using python

```
python get-pip.py
```

Install pymongo using pip

```
pip install pymongo
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04,

For this, the version of the pip should be less than or the same as 9.0.1.

First of all, install the pip for python version 3 from-

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and check pip version-

```
pip --version
```

after that, we have to install build-essential for python-dev

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

and python setup-tools

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And finally, we are able to install pymongo by following command-

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

It worked for me, may it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these commands

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

To get a specific version of pymongo:

```
$ python -m pip install pymongo==3.1.1
```

To upgrade using pip:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pymongo
```

To use easy_install from setuptools do:

```
$ python -m easy_install pymongo
```

To upgrade do:

```
$ python -m easy_install -U pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can download the .egg file [here](https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymongo/) and install with

```
sudo easy_install //filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Windows 10:

```
pip install -- upgrade pymongo
```

Answer (score -1):

```
For ubuntu , you can try...
sudo pip3 install pymongo

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

It works for me

Answer (score -1):

I'm running python 2.7.12 on Rasbian Jesse. After running:

```
pip install pymongo
```

The following command reveals that the pymongo module exists under */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*

```
pip show pymongo
```

One methods that works is to append the sys path with the location of the pymongo module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
import pymongo
```